# using input's value to find a rails object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, custom-data-attribute

I want to grab an input's value in the html and use it in my ruby code like this. Any ideas?

```
<input type="hidden" id="useThis" value="1">

<% @user = User.find( <I want to grab the above input's value here>  ) %>
```

Comment: Is this in the same view file? If so, however you set the "1", do the same thing there. Otherwise, you'll need to employ some javascript to grab that element, grab the value, then plug it in there, or use it to fire off some AJAX that renders that partial you want, and then you'll be dealing with just Ruby and ERB.

Comment: sounds like i'll need to do some javascript to grab the element and then grab the value thanks man

Comment: How is the input tag generated, particularly the value? Can you use the same expression that generated that in the `find`? Also, code that finds an object usually belongs in a model or controller, not a view. You cannot use javascript to pass the value to the ruby code. The ruby is finished running by the time your JS runs. You need to provide more information about the data and logic flow that you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: the value is being set using jquery. I have an on click event on a link that has a data attribute on it. I take the value of the data attribute and put it into the value of #useThis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one-liner with nokogiri? This is just an example

```
require 'nokogiri'
s = '<input type="hidden" name="currentRackU" id="currentRackU" value="11">'
Nokogiri::XML.parse(s).root.attributes['id'].value # currentRackU
```

You might need to run gem install nokogiri if you don't have nokogiri installed. Write code like this on controller instead of erb file

```
<% @user = User.find( <I want to grab the above input's value here>  ) %>
```